# Select element in jquery collection by value using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery and have a collection (object?) that contains inputs from the page.  I have a variable that holds the value attribute for each iteration of a loop.  I want to find the input with the value that matches my variable so I can check the checkbox.

```
function reject(el) {
    const checkBox = $(el).find('input:checkbox');
    if (tempStore.checks.length > 0) {
        for (let j=0;j<tempStore.checks.length;j++) {
            $(checkBox).find("input.val("+tempStore.checks[j]+")").checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been searching online for hours and can't find the right syntax.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is set in the DOM, you can try selecting it by [attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with `[value=""]` selector:

```js
let value = "A";

$('body').find('input[value="' + value + '"]').prop("checked", "checked");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="A">
```

Note that in your code you can do:

```
checkBox.filter(...)
```

That will increase performance as it will [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) an already filled element list, instead of [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Another solution (not the best tho) is to select it against [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

```js
let $checks = $('body').find('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    value = "B";
    
$checks.each(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  
  if ($this.val() == value) {
    $this.prop("checked", "checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" value="C">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) by passing a comparison function.

```js
// Reset state
let $checkbox = $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
let valuesToCheck = ['1', '4'];

$checkbox.filter(function() {
  return valuesToCheck.includes(this.value)
}).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" value="5">
```

Same thing, using arrow function syntax (you can't rely on 'this' to be set)

```
$checkbox.filter((i, e) => valuesToCheck.includes(e.value)).prop('checked', true);
```

Some comments about your original code:

- You don't need `> 0' in your`if` statement, since '0' is a falsey value.
- You don't need the `if` at all, since the condition in the `for` will never be true and never run.
- Inside the `for` you are converting a jQuery collection to a jQuery collection. No need, just use `checkbox`.
- Lastly, you are trying to `find` a `input` element inside a collection that consists of `input` elements, so you won't find anything. You should use `checkBox.filter(...)`.

Putting it all together:

```
function reject(el) {
    const $checkBox = $(el).find('input:checkbox');
        for (let j=0;j<tempStore.checks.length;j++) {
            $checkBox.filter((i,e) => e.value == tempStore.checks[j]).prop('checked', true)
        }
    }
}
```